# Como criar um TextView e uma ImageView via código?

Tags: java, android, xml

Gostaria de saber como cria via código um `TextView` e uma `ImageView` e destrui-lo via código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para criar uma view qualquer em memória é simples, mas a maioria dos problemas é quando não aparece nada no ecra, portanto asegure-se que ela fique visível como no caso da ImageView se não tiver uma imagem não ira aparecer nada, e se não adicionar a nenhuma layout é totalmente impossivel aparecer.
Então no caso da TextView:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Alguma coisa");

//Suponhamos que temos uma layout com um id layoutVertical
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutVertical);
linear.addView(textView);
```

No caso da imageView seria algo parecido menos a parte de que se tem de adicionar uma imagem:

```
ImageView imagem = new ImageView(this);
imagem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagemqualquer);
```

No caso de apagar o que teria de fazer seria remover as views da layout em que estavam, no caso do exemplo anterior para remover a textView teriamos de fazer:

```
linear.removeView(textView);
```

Desde o momento em que já não é utilizada ou chamado o objeto TextView o `garbage Collector` o limpa e não ocupa mais a memória. Mas ainda se quiser pode também esconder a view sem a apagar:

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```